# Add two Rows then divide by a row

Tags: r, tidyverse

So I have a data set. I need to add every other row and divided by the second row. Row 2 divided by (Row 1 + Row 2)

```
1   10779
2   911
3   13897
4   2780
5   13552
6   1112
7   15352
8   2036
9   11779
10  790
```

So for this data, I would need [Row 2 / (Row 1 + Row 2)] so (911/(10779+911)) and [Row 4 / (Row 3 + Row 4] etc.  I am close to using tidyverse but can't quite get it.

Comment: If you're not doing a "lag" operation (since you don't calculate "row3/(row2+row3)", is it safe to assume that you have an even number of rows? Would it make sense to have two columns instead of one?

Comment: Yes, so basically I am trying to find the ration between rows. So I need to aggregate both rows and then divide by the second row for every pair of rows in my data set.

Comment: My point is that the data might be better organized into two columns instead of one, something like: `ind <- seq(1, nrow(x), by=2); data.frame(a=x[ind,], b=x[ind+1,])`

Comment: SO when I do that I get an error that says Error in seq.default(1, nrow(float4[, 7]), by = 2) : 
  'to' must be of length 1

Comment: That's because you are using `nrow` incorrectly. It returns the `n`umber of `row`s for a `data.frame` or `matrix`, where it appears that you passed a single column (which is converted to a vector, so ... it doesn't have the concept of "rows" in R). Had you done `nrow(float4[,7,drop=FALSE])` or much more simply `nrow(float4)`, it should work.

Comment: I think I am understanding what you mean, but I pulled a singular column off of my entire matrix because that is the only one I care about. Does that make sense?

Comment: No need to debate this, just see my answer. If you want the length of a vector, then you use `length`. If you want the number of rows of a matrix or frame, then you use `nrow`. Don't confuse the two, and you need to understand what you need in that `seq` call: some number that indicates how far you want to count. That is all.\

Comment: Ohhh got you, sorry I didn't mean to debate. Now I see what you mean. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
df <- read_table("v1 v2
1   10779
2   911
3   13897
4   2780
5   13552
6   1112
7   15352
8   2036
9   11779
10  790")


df %>%
  mutate(grp = (v1 - 1) %/% 2) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarize(v = v2[2] / (sum(v2)))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>     grp      v
#>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     0 0.0779
#> 2     1 0.167 
#> 3     2 0.0758
#> 4     3 0.117 
#> 5     4 0.0629
```

Though I would second @r2evans's comment that this data may be better organized by spreading the rows into separate columns. This will let you be a bit more expressive about the ratio you're trying to create. Here's an example:

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(grp = (v1 - 1) %/% 2,
         rank = (v1 - 1) %% 2 + 1) %>%
  select(-v1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = rank, values_from = v2, names_prefix = "Row") %>%
  mutate(val = Row2 / (Row1 + Row2))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>     grp  Row1  Row2    val
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     0 10779   911 0.0779
#> 2     1 13897  2780 0.167 
#> 3     2 13552  1112 0.0758
#> 4     3 15352  2036 0.117 
#> 5     4 11779   790 0.0629
```

Comment: This seems to work, I am a little confused as to why though?

Comment: actually I am getting an error saying cant apply to type numeric

Comment: So have 72 columns instead of rows?

Comment: No, you won't want to spread all of your rows out. The idea is you have pairs of rows. Each pair of rows has a first row & a second row. You can rearrange so that you have one column that tells you which pair ('grp' in my example), and then you have one column for the first row of the pair ('Row1') and another column for the second row of the pair ('Row2').

Comment: It's hard to say where exactly that error is coming from without seeing the structure of your dataset. If you can paste your actual dataframe (or a small portion of it) using `dput` that would make it easier to see what's happening

Answer (score 2):

I think your data can be re-organized by column. This code takes every other row and puts them into their own column:

```r
ind <- seq(1, nrow(dat), by = 2)
dat2 <- data.frame(V1 = dat[ind,], V2=dat[ind+1,])
dat2
#      V1   V2
# 1 10779  911
# 2 13897 2780
# 3 13552 1112
# 4 15352 2036
# 5 11779  790
```

From here, your math is straight-forward `data.frame` operations, whether base, tidy, or datatable:

### Base

```r
with(dat2, V2 / (V1 + V2))
# [1] 0.07792985 0.16669665 0.07583197 0.11709225 0.06285305
```

or as a new column:

```r
within(dat2, { newcol = V2 / (V1 + V2) })
#      V1   V2     newcol
# 1 10779  911 0.07792985
# 2 13897 2780 0.16669665
# 3 13552 1112 0.07583197
# 4 15352 2036 0.11709225
# 5 11779  790 0.06285305
```

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
dat2 %>%
  mutate(newcol = V2 / (V1 + V2))
#      V1   V2     newcol
# 1 10779  911 0.07792985
# 2 13897 2780 0.16669665
# 3 13552 1112 0.07583197
# 4 15352 2036 0.11709225
# 5 11779  790 0.06285305
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat2)[, newcol := V2 / (V1 + V2) ][]
#       V1   V2     newcol
# 1: 10779  911 0.07792985
# 2: 13897 2780 0.16669665
# 3: 13552 1112 0.07583197
# 4: 15352 2036 0.11709225
# 5: 11779  790 0.06285305
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Lag=lag(V2),Val=V2/(V2+Lag))

   V1    V2   Lag        Val
1   1 10779    NA         NA
2   2   911 10779 0.07792985
3   3 13897   911 0.93847920
4   4  2780 13897 0.16669665
5   5 13552  2780 0.82978202
6   6  1112 13552 0.07583197
7   7 15352  1112 0.93245870
8   8  2036 15352 0.11709225
9   9 11779  2036 0.85262396
10 10   790 11779 0.06285305
```

Comment: No not exactly. I need one new value for each row. Not continuously.
So I need (Row 2 / (Row1 +Row 2) Then I need (Row 4 / (Row 3 + Row 4)
Essentially I am cutting the data in half.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (but not tidyverse):

```
vector<-c(10779,911,13897,2780,13552,1112,15352,2036,11779,790)    
sapply(c(2:length(vector)),function(x){
      vector[x]/(vector[x-1]+vector[x])
    },simplify=TRUE)
```

Comment: I get this error kicked back out. 

Error in vector[x] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: The code above is an example considering your object (in vector format) is named "vector"...

Comment: So this is really close, except I need it for each specific row pair.
(Row 1 and Row 2)
(Row 3 and Row 4)

Comment: I do not want row 2 and row 3 to be included.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
library(dplyr)
a=seq(1:10)
b=c(10779,911,13897,2780,13552,1112,15352,2036,11779,790)
d=c(0,b[1:9])
c=b+d
df=data.frame(a,b,ratio)
df <- data.frame(col1= a, col2 = b,ratio=ratio)
df %>% dplyr::filter(row_number() %% 2 == 0)

#Output
# col1 col2      ratio
# 1    2  911 0.07792985
# 2    4 2780 0.16669665
# 3    6 1112 0.07583197
# 4    8 2036 0.11709225
# 5   10  790 0.06285305
```